# Can I use WordPress blog as a subfolder of my main domain?

Tags: node.js, wordpress, amazon-web-services, angular, nginx

I am developing an MEAN stack application and I have a WordPress blog for our website as well. I would like to integrate WordPress blog as part of the webapp in main domain like www.example.com/blog instead of blog.example.com.

How can I configure the WordPress blog as part of the Angular node application.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For something to be accessible at `HOST/url`. It doesn't necessarily has to be a subfolder. It can reside anywhere in your system as far as it is accessible from your web server application.

Here, if you are using a web-server program like Nginx or Apache web server you can add a config in that to send any request pointing to `/url` (say `/blog` in your case) to the folder where your wordpress blog is located. Like (for nginx):

```
location /blog {
    index index.php;
    root /var/www/blog/public;
}
```

If you are not using nginx or apache over node.js i.e. node.js is directly listening to the external port then you can use [node-php](https://github.com/mkschreder/node-php) to create a route at `/blog` and place wordpress folder at the respective path.

```
var express = require('express');
var php = require("node-php"); 
var path = require("path"); 

var app = express();

app.use("/", php.cgi("/path/to/wordpress")); 

app.listen(9090);
```

If wordpress is on another server then you can proxy pass all requests to /blog to that server. Like (for nginx):

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name mydomain.com;
    location /blog {
      proxy_pass http://second_instance_internal_ip:80;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
    location / {
      proxy_pass http://this_instance_ip_for_node.js_app:9000;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Sumit Sinha for clarifying me. I am going to use Nginx server for my node application and my wordpress blog is going to be in different EC2 instance , How can I actually route it to the host/blog url.

Comment: If wordpress is on a different server then you will have to proxy pass it to the other server. Its just like configuring the server for node.js application on nginx.

Comment: Could you please share me an example snippet or something on this ?

Comment: Thanks brother for your help! :) @Sumit Sinha

Comment: When I use it with https version of my domain routing is been automatically redirected to multiple times. How can I setup this properly,

Comment: @SureshKumarS Infinite redirection? There is a redirection loop some where? Checkout if something is calling back the caller?

Answer (score 0):

I think a lot of people have been using this [WP JSON API](https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/)

If you are using AWS you could create a WP instance and in your angular application have a service that calls the API and renders the blog posts inside angular

Comment: Thanks @Edward Smith for the info. But with that Api could you please give me how can I populate the images which are present as part of my blog post and also the other meta data.

Answer (score 0):

Create a CloudFront distribution with two origin servers (your nodeJS server and your wordpress server). Configure it to serve the wordpress content at `/blog`.